# How to pass in a ratio in fractional form?

Tags: calculations

How to pass in a ratio of 4/15 (instead of its approximated decimal form of 0.266) to table definition.

---

Final solution can be seen [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7801/how-to-use-pgfmathsetmacro-to-create-a-ratio-that-can-be-passed-to-table-colu/7806#7806).

---

I need one more vote to close this topic.

Comment: But, if you have another solution, welcome!

Comment: Unfortunately, the `\ratio` above cannot accept dimensionless values such as `\ratio{4}{15}`. :-(

Comment: If you want some overkill, you could use pgfmathparse.

Comment: @Caramdir, I will revisit this tomorrow. Thank you for commenting.

Comment: @xport: Only the first comment in your `\ratio` macro is necessary.

Comment: @TH, can you post your comment as your answer? I cannot understand without compilable code snippet.

Comment: @xport: You have to use "@TH." _including_ the "."; otherwise you won't notify TH. What TH means is that in your definition of `\ratio` after "Comparing accuracy", most of the `%` signs are not needed. For example, if a line ends with a command such as `\strip@pt`, then there's no need for the `%` since TeX doesn't see spaces after macros anyway. (I had also wanted to comment on that.)

Comment: @Hendrik, this site uses notification system based on @displayname? I just know it from you.

Comment: @xport: You need to write at least 3 letters of the user name; then he gets a notification. (Didn't you wonder why we're writing `@xport` all the time? `:-)`)

Comment: @Hendrik, In my experience joining forum, we use `@name` to refer the person with whom we want to talk.

Comment: @xport: Yes, and since you used at least 3 letters of my name, I just got a notification that you addressed this comment to me. Otherwise I wouldn't have found it.

Comment: @Hendrik, I see. So if I want to call all members, I just need to type all names. That is fun!

Comment: @xport: Luckily this doesn't work. For details have a look [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598/when-writing-a-comment-how-do-i-ensure-that-the-person-it-is-addressed-to-gets-n/599#599).

Comment: @xport: By the way, here's an example where your question became much too long. Somehow it's not clear anymore what the question is. For example, in your "EDIT 3", the "comparing accuracy" part is not part of the question. At least I don't know why you put it there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use `\pgfmathsetmacro` to create a ratio that can be passed  to table column definition?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7801/how-to-use-pgfmathsetmacro-to-create-a-ratio-that-can-be-passed-to-table-colu)

Comment: @xport: You're not the first person to omit the period, don't worry. It's my own fault for choosing as short a name as possible.

Comment: @TH. I also didn't know the notification system works using a "strange" way.

Comment: The exact way the notification syntax works is described in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020

Comment: @xport: Dear xport, please don't make such heavy edits anymore in the future. You started with a short question, it got longer, then you wrote "case closed", then you made it even longer, then after my comment it got shorter (good), then you noted that it's a possible duplicate of another question of yours that you asked **on the same day**, and now an extremely short version is left where I can't imagine anymore why you asked the question. Please try and ask _less_, but _more focussed_ questions.

Comment: @Hendrik, thanks for the suggestion. I started this topic prior to the second one. The second one was intended for pgf approach. Then @Joseph gave an answer on the second thread but his answer based on TeX approach. I struggled to use @Joseph solution and it worked and finally I decided to forget about the initial idea using pgf. Yesterday I changed the title of the second thread from pgf to more TeX approach and closed the first one. Thanks.

Comment: @xport: Ah, I see. Thanks for explaining. Then I'll also vote to close this one. (It is not closed yet!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Joseph's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7801/how-to-pass-in-a-ratio-in-fraction-form-as-opposed-to-decimal-form-to-table-col/7806#7806).

Answer (score 5):

If you want more accurate calculations use the **fp** package.

For example using the fp package as shown below you get `0.999999999999999998` rather than 
`0.998`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{fp}
\begin{document}
  \parindent0pt
  \FPdiv\paramtwo{4}{15}
  \FPdiv\paramthree{2}{15}
  \FPmul\paramtemp{4}{\paramthree}
  \FPdiv\paramseven{3}{15}
  \FPadd\total{\paramseven}{\paramtemp}
  \FPadd\total{\total}{\paramtwo}

  \total
\end{document}
```

No need for any manual calculations!

You can use it in a tabular as follows (remember it creates variable names on the fly)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{fp}

\FPdiv\columni{3.9999999}{3.8888888}
\FPdiv\columnii{1.11123456}{1.3999999}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{\columni cm}|p{\columnii cm}|}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{tabular}
```

\end{document}

Comment: @Yiannis, thanks for answering. It is useful.

Comment: @Yiannis, how to define a newcommand with 2 inputs and produces the ratio between the inputs? Internally the newcommand use `\FPdiv` of course. I don't understand the manual of fp.sty. It is very short and difficult to understand.

Comment: @xport \def\division#1#2{
  \FPdiv\result{#1}{#2}
  \result
}

\division{2}{9999}

Comment: @Yiannis, please kindly see again my last update above.

Comment: @xport: I didn't check for sure, but the problem is that the `\FP` macros are not expandable. You're going to have to do the division before you need to use the result in an expandable manner.

Comment: @xport See my edit for how to use them.

Comment: @Yiannis, I have tried, it works but not so portable compared to Joseph's solution. Please see my final update and visit the given link.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see a gap with a zoom of 400% ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\parindent=0pt
\textwidth=15cm
\begin{document}

\rule{\textwidth}{5mm}

\rule{0.2667\textwidth}{5mm}%
\rule{0.1333\textwidth}{5mm}%
\rule{0.1333\textwidth}{5mm}%
\rule{0.1333\textwidth}{5mm}%
\rule{0.1333\textwidth}{5mm}%
\rule{0.2\textwidth}{5mm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: because you took more accurate decimal numbers. You lost only 0.0001 in total. :-)

Comment: even though there is no gap by taking more accurate decimal ratios, doing conversion manually is tedious.