# How to pass in a ratio in fraction form (as opposed to decimal form) to table column definition?

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations

My scenario is to pass in a ratio (in fractional form as opposed to decimal form) to  each table column definition.

**The following code cannot be compiled.**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcommand{\ratio}[2]%
{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\temp{(#1)/(#2)}%
    \temp%
}

\newcolumntype{A}[1]%
{%
    >{}%
    m{#1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}%
    <{}%
}

\begin{document}
\ratio{1}{2}
\ratio{2}{5}

\begin{longtable}{|A{\ratio{1}{2}}|A{\ratio{1}{2}}|}\hline
A & B \tabularnewline\hline
A & B \tabularnewline\hline

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Josephs solution works for me (after adding `\end{longtable}` to the code).

Comment: It seems to me that your `#1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth` doesn't work. I'm not sure what's happening, but I get a "-2" in the table.

Comment: @Hendrik, you need `calc.sty`.

Comment: Then why didn't you include `\usepackage{calc}` in your code above? I'd suggest you remove the whole piece starting from "Joseph's solution does not work"; his code does work. You just forgot `\end{longtable}` as the error message says and as Caramdir already noted.

Comment: @Hendrik, I did not read well. Yes. It works :-) We need copy to clipboard button.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use `\pgfmathsetratio` here, as the arguments to the `m` box needs to expand to a number. Assuming you can use the e-TeX extensions then you can use an alternative definition:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\ratio[2]{%
  \strip@pt\dimexpr#1pt/#2\relax
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. It works after correcting my own code.