# Passing arguments to \def inside \newcommand (TikZ/PGF)

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, programming

I'm having trouble passing an argument to `\pgfmathparse` inside a macro I defined. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\drawmestg}[2]{
    \def\endpt{\pgfmathparse{#1+#2}\pgfmathresult}
    \draw (0,0) -- (\endpt,0);
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \drawmestg{1}{1}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I must confess, I'm quite clueless why I get the error:

```
Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 14
```

Comment: This is all to do with expansion. As well as Peter's answer, you might want to look for example at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7811/how-to-use-pgf-math-inside-an-argument

Comment: I guess I really need to sit down and study a bit this *expandability* thing... It keep s popping up, but I don't really get it - yet! :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the `\draw` command in your version `\endpt` is expanded to `\pgfmathparse{#1+#2}\pgfmathresult`. So you get

```
\draw (0,0) -- (\pgfmathparse{#1+#2}\pgfmathresult,0);
```

which greatly confuses TikZ.

Instead you should set `\endpt` to the *result* of the calculation, either via

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\endpt}{#1+#2}
```

as Peter suggested or equivalently via

```
\pgfmathparse{#1+#2}
\edef\endpt{\pgfmathresult}
```

Alternatively for this MWE you can of course simply do

```
\newcommand{\drawmestg}[2]{
    \draw (0,0) -- ({#1+#2},0);
}
```

Comment: I like this answer because it took me one year of using TikZ before I figured out how to use arbitrary math in coordinates.  The manual never says!

Answer (score 9):

Simply use `pgfmathsetmacro` as in:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\endpt}{#1+#2}
```

Comment: @CountZero: Or `\pgfmathparse{#1+#2}\let\endpt\pgfmathresult`, which however is basically the same. The `\enpt` must be expandable, and `\pgfmathparse` isn't, so it can't be part of the macro.