# pgfmathsetmacro, pgfmarthparse, pgfmathresult to define command with calculation

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath, pgfmathparse, tikzmath

I am quite new to using `tikz` and the `pgf` package in general, and I'm having a hard time understanding how/when to use `pgfmathsetmacro`, `pgfmathparse` and `pgfmathresult`. I have the following problem: I am trying to define a command for a linear transformation that I want to use inside TikZ. The transformation is given by

[image]

I thought about defining a command that takes an input argument and predefined values of `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` and returns the mapped coordinate, which I will then use in a `\coordinate` definition. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

% Define mapping coordinates to map [a,b] -> [c,d]. Do it separately for x and y
\tikzmath{\ax = 1; \bx = 2;
          \ay = 1; \by = 2;
          \c = 0;  \d = 1;}

% Define the transformation as a new command that uses pgf's math engine. It takes 1 input argument
% I don't know how to define this properly, it does not give me any error but I think it is wrong
\newcommand{\transformX}[1]{\pgfmathparse{((\c+\d) + (\d-\c)*((2*{#1} - (\ax+\bx))/(\bx-\ax)))/2}\pgfmathresult}
\newcommand{\transformY}[1]{\pgfmathparse{((\c+\d) + (\d-\c)*((2*{#1} - (\ay+\by))/(\by-\ay)))/2}\pgfmathresult}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1in,y=1in]
    \coordinate (myCoord) at (\transformX{1.5},\transformY{1.4}); % error
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I thought that `pgfmathsetmacro`, `pgmathparse` or functions alike should do the trick, but I do not know how to implement them. I read [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337831/pgfmathparse-basic-usage) and [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35218/passing-arguments-to-def-inside-newcommand-tikz-pgf) (the latter I believe is very similar to what I'm trying to achieve) but I could not adapt to my case.

Any ideas on what to do? Thanks!

Comment: The main deficiency of `pgfmath` is its lack of expandability. I'd generally use the nowadays LaTeX built-in floating point capabilities. That is, replacing `\pgfmathparse` with `\fpeval` and removing `\pgfmathresult`.

Comment: Thanks @AlexG this actually worked for me! I am trying to understand the concept of "expandability" as I've seen in other posts. I was actually trying to use `\transformX{1.5+0.5}` and it did not work. However, using `\transformX{\fpeval{1.5+0.5}}` worked. From this I understand that "expandability" means that the result of calculations is not evaluated directly if we don't ask LaTeX to do so. Is that correct? Thanks again

Comment: If you're doing more complicated mathematics, you should check out the [sagetex](https://ctan.org/pkg/sagetex)  package which gives you access to a computer algebra system. The problem [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/637792/how-to-get-set-the-precision-of-the-pgfplots/637845#637845) shows how `sagetex` can do the calculations for tikz. The post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/662506/xfp-huge-integers-why-is-inteval-less-accurate-then-fpeval/662790#662790) shows how Sage can handle calculations that LaTeX is just not designed to solve.